# I have 4 different solutions of a probability question that I don't have the answer. What would the question be for each solution I provided?

Tags: probability

Ques: A survey on 500 people shows that 50 of them don't read Newspaper A, 25 don't read Newspaper B. 10 of them don't read any of the two papers. A person is randomly selected. What is the probability that he reads paper B but not paper A?

Solution: Given that, n(A)^c= 50; n(B)^c= 25; n(A U B)^c = 10;
So, n(A)= 450; n(B)= 475; n(A U B)= 490;
n(A intersection B) = n(A)+ n(B)-n(A U B) = 435;
n(B intersect A^c)= number of those who read paper B but not paper A = n(B) - n(A intersect B) = 475-435 = 40

If the calculations above are correct, I have more than one solutions among which I can't figure out which one is right and why not the others.

Solution 1 : Probability of those who read B but not A= P(B intersect A^c) = n(B intersect A^c)/ n(U) = 40/500 =2/25

Solution 2 : P(B) = n(B)/500 = 475/500 ; P(A^c) = n(A^c)/500 = 50/500;
Hence applying multiplication rule for independent events, P(B intersect A^c) = P(B) * P(A^c) = (475 * 50)/(500 * 500) = 19/200 ;

Sol 3 : A different interpretation of the line "What is the probability that he reads paper B but not paper A".
What they are asking is basically this = what is the probability of people reading paper B GIVEN  THAT they don't read paper A [they asked the prob. of reading paper B with the **condition being not reading A**] = P(B|A^c) = n(B intersect A^c)/n(A^c) = 40/50 = 4/5

Sol 4: Another interpretation of the same line "What is the probability that he reads paper B but not paper A"

What they are asking is basically this = what is the probability of people not reading paper A GIVEN  THAT they read paper B[**condition being he reads paper B**] = P(A^c|B) = 40/475

I thought Sol 1 is right and don't understand why sol 2 is producing different answer. **Assuming sol 1 is right and 2 isn't** means the events are dependent, right? And if they are dependent, then why neither 3 nor 4 gives same answer for sol 1? In that case, sol 1 isn't right but sol 2 is.
If so, why sol 1 isn't right?
If you could say in words what the questions would have been for each of the sol 1, 2, 3, and 4?

I would really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's desired is not a conditional probability, but the probability of the intersection.  Nothing in the problem statement suggests the conditional.

Comment: Recall... $\Pr(X\cap Y)=\Pr(X)\cdot \Pr(Y)$ is true if **and only if** $X$ and $Y$ are independent events.  Here, not reading paper $A$ and not reading paper $B$ are **not** independent.

Comment: Just a typesetting tip: if you surround math with dollar signs, it will often render better. For example ```$P(A^c) = n(A^c)/500 = 50/500$``` renders as $P(A^c) = n(A^c)/500 = 50/500$.  You can read a tutorial on it here  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @JMoravitz - If two events are dependent then $P(B ∩ A^c) = P(B) * P(A^c|B) = 2/25 = sol 1$ 
Got it now. Thank you.